# Role of default template parameters in overload resolution of (partially specialized) class templates

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, partial-specialization, default-arguments

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701381/9908011) explains the behaviour of the following program:

```
template<typename A, typename B = int >
struct FirstWins {
    static constexpr int i = 1;
};
template<typename A>
struct FirstWins<A, float/* anything different from int */ > {
    static constexpr int i = 2;
};

template<typename A, typename B = int >
struct SecondWins {
    static constexpr int i = 1;
};
template<typename A>
struct SecondWins<A, int > {
    static constexpr int i = 2;
};

int main()
{
    typedef void Whatever_t;
    cout << FirstWins < Whatever_t >::i << endl;  // prints 1
    cout << SecondWins< Whatever_t >::i << endl;  // prints 2
    return 0;
}
```

However, I cannot find an actual reference describing explicitly this behaviour and thus confirming the answer.

I could not find on cppreference.com a sentence confirming that explicit template arguments are preferred over default ones.

I suspect that this is not really the rule. The rule is that whenever there is a partial template specialization matching the template arguments, that specialization is always chosen over the instantiation of the primary template. Is this correct? (in this case, [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization#Partial_ordering) somehow explain this rule, but again not explicitly).

Comment: A default parameter just supplies a type when the code doesn't. It has no effect on selecting the specialization.

Comment: I think you're confused about what default template arguments are used for. In your example, it just means that `FirstWins<X>` resolves as `FirstWins<X, int>`. The actual selection of the definition of `FirstWins<X, int>` happens after the "substitution" of `B` for `int`.

Comment: @Holt: sure, but my question really pertains `SecondWins<X, int>`. In that case, `SecondWins<X, int>` is preferred over `SecondWins<X, =int>`.

Comment: @L.Bruce Because `SecondWins<A, B=int>` is no different than `SecondWins<A, B>` for template selection, and so the specialization `SecondsWins<A, int>` is preferred over the non-specialized one. The default template argument has no impact here for the resolution.

Comment: @Holt: Well, in a way it does have impact, I believe. Look at `FirstWins`. There it is the mismatch between the default parameter `B=int` and the explicit one `float` that leads to the selection of the first. `B` defaulting to anything that is not `float` does make the difference.

Comment: @L.Bruce It has an impact on what `FirstWins<X>` and `SecondWins<X>` extends to, that's all. `FirstWins<Whatever_t>` extends to `FirstWins<Whatever_t, int>`, which does not match the specialization, which is why the non-specialized version is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename A, typename B = int >
struct S {
//...
};
```

Can be seen as

```
template<typename A, typename B = int >
struct S;
// So S<A> is S<A, int>

// Primary template
template<typename A, typename B>
struct S
{
   //...
};

// Possible specialization as
template<typename A>
struct S<A, int>
{
   //...
};
```

then, it is more clear which instantiation to use.