# Trying to specialize a template function based on the presence of a typedef within class

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae, template-specialization

I want to be able to customize handling of a struct based on the presence of a type within the struct (without writing any additional code per custom struct), like:

```
struct Normal_t
{
};

struct Custom_t
{
    using my_custom_type = bool;
};
```

It seems like I should be able to do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
template <class T, typename Enabler = void>
struct has_custom_type
{
    bool operator()() { return false; }
};

template <class T>
struct has_custom_type<T, typename T::my_custom_type>
{
    bool operator()() { return true; }
};

bool b_normal = has_custom_type<Normal_t>()();  // returns false
bool b_custom = has_custom_type<Custom_t>()();  // returns false, INCORRECT? should return true?
```

What I don't understand is that the standard library uses something similar but seemingly more convoluted for its type traits.  For example, this works:

```
template<bool test, class T = void>
struct my_enable_if
{
};

template<class T>
struct my_enable_if<true, T>
{
    using type = T;
};

template <class T, class Enabler = void>
struct foo
{
    bool operator()() { return false; }
};

template <class T>
struct foo<T, typename my_enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type>
{
    bool operator()() { return true; }
};

bool foo_float = foo<float>()();    // returns false
bool foo_int = foo<int>()();        // returns true
```

In both cases, the specialization is happening based on the presence of a type within a struct, in one case `typename T::my_custom_type` and in the other `typename my_enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type`.  Why does the second version work but not the first?

I came up with this workaround using the ... parameter pack syntax, but I'd really like to understand if there is a way to do this using normal template specialization without using the parameter pack syntax, and if not, why.

```
template<typename ...Args>                              
bool has_custom_type_2(Args&& ...args)      { return false; }   

template<class T, std::size_t = sizeof(T::my_custom_type)>  
bool has_custom_type_2(T&)                  { return true; }

template<class T, std::size_t = sizeof(T::my_custom_type)>  
bool has_custom_type_2(T&&)                 { return true; }    /* Need this T&& version to handle has_custom_type_2(SomeClass()) where the parameter is an rvalue */

bool b2_normal = has_custom_type_2(Normal_t()); // returns false
bool b2_custom = has_custom_type_2(Custom_t()); // returns true - CORRECT!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you specify default `void` type for `Enabler`, but `T::my_custom_type` is not `void`. Either use `bool` as default type, or use `std::void_t` that always returns `void`:

```
template <class T, typename = void>
struct has_custom_type : std::false_type { };

template <class T>
struct has_custom_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::my_custom_type>> : std::true_type { };
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18701381/1625187) explains why types should match.

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly what I wanted.  Changing that default type was the one thing I hadn't tried.  Thank you also for pointing out std::void_t and the use of std::true_type/false_type.  I think I now understand why the types need to match:  when the template is instantiated by `has_custom_type<Custom_t>`, the compiler first _only_ looks at the base template and says "ok, the template parameters are set to <Custom_t,void>", and only after that does it look for specializations that match and are more specific.

Comment: @JamesThrush, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

As explained by others, if you set a `void` default value for the second template parameter, your solution works only if `my_custom_type` is `void`.

If `my_custom_type` is `bool`, you can set `bool` the default value. But isn't a great solution because loose generality.

To be more general, you can use SFINAE through something that fail if `my_custom_type` doesn't exist but return ever the same type (`void`, usually) if `my_custom_type` is present.

Pre C++17 you can use `decltype()`, `std::declval` and the power of comma operator

```
template <class T, typename Enabler = void>
struct has_custom_type
 { bool operator()() { return false; } };

template <class T>
struct has_custom_type<T,
   decltype( std::declval<typename T::my_custom_type>(), void() )>
 { bool operator()() { return true; } };
```

Starting from C++17 it's simpler because you can use `std::void_t` (see Evg's answer, also for the use of `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` instead of defining an `operator()`).

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T, typename Enabler = void> // <== void set as default template parameter type
struct has_custom_type
{
    bool operator()() { return false; }
};

template <class T>
struct has_custom_type<T, typename T::my_custom_type>
{
    bool operator()() { return true; }
};
```

The specialization matches when it gets the template parameters `<T, bool>`.   However, when you just specify `<T>`, without a second type, then it goes to the default type you specified `=void` to come up with the call `<T, void>`, which doesn't match your `bool` specialization.

Live example showing it matches with explicit `<T, bool>`: https://godbolt.org/z/MEJvwT